# How to output a list of dataframes, which is able to be used by another user

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list whose elements are several dataframes, which looks like this
[image]

Because it is hard for another user to use these data by re-running my original code. Hence, I would like to export it. As the graph shows, the dataframes in that list have different number of rows. I am wondering if there is any method to export it as file without damaging any information, and make it be able to be used by Rstudio. I have tried to save it as RData, but I don't know how to save the information.
Thanks a lot

Comment: When you save the list `DATA`, it will save all the information contained in it like row and column number of the data.frames. Maybe your question is not clear...

Comment: You can use the `saveRDS` function if you only have one object to store (DATA), and the other users can use `readRDS` to load it

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I am going to try

Answer (score 0):

To output objects in R, here are 4 common methods:

- `dput()` writes a text representation of an R object

This is very convenient if you want to allow someone to get your object by copying and pasting text (for instance on this site), without having to email or upload and download a file. The downside however is that the output is long and re-reading the object into R (simply by assigning the copied text to an object) can hang R for large objects. This works best to create reproducible examples. For a list of data frames, this would not be a very good option.

- You can print an object to a `.csv`, `.xlsx`, etc. file with `write.table()`, `write.csv()`, `readr::write_csv()`, `xlsx::write.xlsx()`, etc.

While the file can then be used by other software (and re-imported into R with `read.csv()`, `readr::read_csv()`, `readxl::read_excel()`, etc.), the data can be transformed in the process and some objects cannot be printed in a single file without prior modifications. So this is not ideal in your case either.

- `save.image()` saves your entire workspace (objects + environment)

The workspace can then be recreated with `load()`. This can be useful, but you are here only interested in saving one object. In that case, it is preferable to use:

- `saveRDS()` which allows to write one object to file

The object can then be re-created with `readRDS()`. This is the best option to save an R object to file, without any modification and then re-create it.

In your situation, this is definitely the best solution.